# Magento - How to Resize Product Thumbnails

Tags: magento, grid, catalog

I am using a Magento extension to control my color swatches. This module also controls catalog list thumbnails. I have experience using resize, but it doesn't seem to be working at the moment.

In developer mode, I have enabled Template Path Hints and it tells me that it's in frontend/.../default/template/catalog/product/list.phtml (typical directory)

Issue: Before clicking, the images default at the correct size. But when I click the thumbnails, they resize to 135x135(skewed, and lower res).

my products-grid in list.phtml:

```
    <ul class="products-grid">
    <?php endif ?>
        <li class="item<?php if(($i-1)%$_columnCount==0): ?> first<?php elseif($i%$_columnCount==0): ?> last<?php endif; ?>">
            <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" class="product-image"><img id="<?php echo $_product->getId();?>" src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(146,196); ?>" width="146" height="196" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" /></a>
            <h2 class="product-name"><a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true) ?>"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?></a></h2>
            <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock("colorselectorplus/listswatch")->setTemplate("colorselectorplus/listswatches.phtml")->setData('product', $_product)->toHtml(); ?>
            <?php if($_product->getRatingSummary()): ?>
            <?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, 'short') ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>

        </li>
    <?php if ($i%$_columnCount==0 || $i==$_collectionSize): ?>
    </ul>
```

If I am correct, this should be controlled by

```
    resize(146,196)
```

Is it possible that onclick the images are loaded by a different phtml?

Thanks! Let me know if you need a URL. (we're not live yet)
[image]

[image]

I have contacted the author, and read the FAQ. I have yet to hear a response.

Comment: would be nice to see this in action. images in popup could be loaded in media.phtml template

Comment: Have you tried contacting the author of the color swatches extension? They might have a FAQ on setting image sizes.

Comment: I've updated the post with images of the issue in my category list.

Comment: To answer your question we should see color swatches extension code. Could you provide download link?

Comment: I added a link to the app folder, and JS included with the extension.

Comment: Please add an answer describing what you had to change and in which core file you did it. Then mark your answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This fix was in a local file pertaining to the module we had installed. Just as simple as editing the resize width/height, but not stored in a user-friendly area.

Answer (score 3):

I have encountered the same issue and contacted the Amasty Support.
Here is the solution they sent me as the above solution is not a solution.

> Our Colors Swatches resize images at this file(lines 78-85):
>   app\code\local\Amasty\Conf\Block\Catalog\Product\View\Type\Configurable.php

```
$parentProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($simple->getParentId());
if($parentProduct){
    $confData[$strKey]['parent_image'] =(string)($this->helper('catalog/image')->init($parentProduct, 'small_image')->resize(135));
    if(!('no_selection' == $simple->getSmallImage() || '' == $simple->getSmallImage())){
        $confData[$strKey]['small_image'] = (string)($this->helper('catalog/image')->init($simple, 'small_image')->resize(135));
    }
    else{
        $confData[$strKey]['small_image'] = (string)($this->helper('catalog/image')->init($parentProduct, 'small_image')->resize(135));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the email... I was simply reviewing the 'first time posters' and yours came up.  My edit was reviewed by other members and unanimously approved - see http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2266921 .  It is common practice on SO to format your code when posting here - I didn't mean any disrespect by it.